Why does tag "file-io" refer to (non-existing) tag "fileinput"?
When asking a question related to file input, I was examining the suggested tag completions.
The "info bubble" for tag "file-io" says "also: fileinput", but I could not find a tag named like that (according to tag completion).
Furthermore, when trying to fix the metadata for tag "file-io" I could not find a reference to "fileinput", so I could not remove it.
So:

Is tag "fileinput" obsolete, and if so
where does the "also:" information come from?


[[tag:fileinput]] is a synonym of [file-io]

Wouldn't it make sense to see "synonym of ..." for the tag when editing it? Where could I see that alias definition? I also failed to open tag "fileinput" for editing.

That's what "also:" means - it lists the synonyms. It shouldn't say "synonym of" because [file-io] is not the synonym, [fileinput] is the synonym. And the target is [file-io]. So [fileinput] is synonym of [file-io]. I linked you to the list of synonyms - it's part of the main tag [file-io]: this is how you get to it. And yes - you can't "update" the synonym. That's what a synonym means - if A is a synonym of B then for all intents and purposes using A just means B. Any usage of A redirects to B.

On "this is how you get it": Isn't it quite counter-intuitive (having to search questions using the tag, just to see the option to see the aliases in turn)? Wouldn't it be more logical to add that information when editing the tag (I said "information", so that does not necessarily include being able to edit that information)?

@U.Windl you can also get to the synonyms from the tag info page (The link to which is present in the search when you're editing tags). Mentioning all the tag synonyms in that space can get a bit messy UX wise and it's not needed there anyway since tagging with the synonym will automatically translate them to the target tag any way.

@U.Windl "quite counter-intuitive (having to search questions using the tag, just to see the option to see the aliases in turn)" that's the tag page. When you click on a tag it does search for questions with that tag but it's also the page with information about the tag you clicked on. SE recently removed the direct link from the popup to the tag info page and there are extremely few other ways to get there. Enter the URL manually or click the ? when editing the tags to a question, or go through the tag page.

If one does a thing frequently enough, they stop thinking about it. To me it's very confusing that "View tag" displays the question using that tag instead of the actual tag information. So for example what's the difference between https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion ("Questions tagged [discussion]") and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/discussion ("Questions tagged [discussion]")

I agree, the label really doesn't make that much sense for what it's trying to describe. I've encountered this before, but promptly forgotten about it.

Correct Title, following the 'Meta'-convention(s), would be: "Why does tag [file-io] refer to (non-existing) tag [fileinput]?" (=> with square brackets around tag names, not double quotes...)
